# How can I add a string to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I've been trying to figure out how add a string to an array.
I have a class which represents a list and I want to add "cup" to the list by calling `addTo`.
I've tried this, but it fills the entire array and then when the method is called again it overwrites the entire array:

```
private String[] option;

private int position;

public Menu()
{
    option = new String[0];
    position = 0;
}

public void addTo(java.lang.String option)
{
    option = new String[20];
    ++position;
    option[position] = option;

}
```

Hope this is better.

Comment: What do you currently think `option = new String[20];` does?

Comment: @immibis it sets the option array's elements to 20 i suppose.

Comment: It creates a new array (`new String[20]`, which creates an array and returns a reference to it) then assigns the reference to `option` (`option =`)

Comment: @midknight And what happens to the "old" `option` array?

Comment: @Tom I declared it before and didn't initialize it     private String [] option;

Comment: You declared the reference. The array the reference refers to is being replaced.

Comment: @midknight And what will happen if you call `#addTo` more than once?

Comment: @Tom it replaces everything in the array with the new call from addTo.

Comment: @midknight And is this what you want? If not, then why do you "reset" the array?

Comment: @Tom no i want it to just print it once and then if i should add another item to it it would print the previous item and the new item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
option = new String[20];
```

is clearing your list.

You should initilize your list only in a constructor, for example.
Your Menu class can be something like:

```
public class Menu{
    private final int LIMIT = 20;
    private String[] option;
    private int position;

    public Menu()
    {
        option = new String[LIMIT];
        position = 0;
    }

    public void addTo(String item)
    {
        if(position == LIMIT)
        {
            // We do not want a IndexOutOfBoundsException here
            return;
        }
        option[position++] = item;
    }

    public void printList(){
        for(int i = 0; i< LIMIT; i++)
        {
            System.out.println( i + ": " + option[i] );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Menu m = new Menu();
        m.addTo("book");
        m.addTo("cup");
        m.addTo("test");

        m.printList();
    }

}
```

Tested and working!

Best regards,

Miguel

Comment: sure i'll edit the post and give the full code for the helper class.

Comment: And what should `LIMIT` be? The array size?

Comment: @midknight `LIMIT` shouldn't be 20, it should be *19* if you like to add 20 elements to the array. That is why I asked him, because the limit check is not "good".

Comment: okay but that code still replaces everything inside the array. I want it to just add it once when the method is called e.g
addTo("cup");
addTo("book");
Then it will print 
cup
book

Comment: LIMIT, in this case, is a constant you should create with the size of your list. Initilize your option[] in your class constructor. Your method addTo() should only add the String to the option[] array. When you use option = new String[20], you lose the reference to the old array.

Comment: @user2711745 If `LIMIT` holds the size of the array, then you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Tom, we don't get and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if we limit the size of the array and the index we use to access it. But you are righ.. We should use LIMIT -1 here... I will edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but downvote for know. As I said, this `if(position == LIMIT)` is wrong if `LIMIT` holds the array size and you increase `position` *after* the check. Simple test, what do you think will happen if `position` is 19 and `LIMIT` still 20? Will it pass your check? Will it successfully insert an item to the array? Luckily you now fixed your old param name `option` ...

Comment: @midknight I suggest to tell us what exactly isn't working. If you change the `addTo` method to `public void addTo(String item) { if (position == LIMIT) { return; } option[position++] = item; }`, then everything is fine here. (Sorry for the formatting)